# switch function?

Tags: r

Hi everyone I have a dataframe which has a column "day" that contains ordinal numbers from 1 to 100. How can I create a function to convert day numbers to day names

Comment: Why do you need to use `switch`? This is not something one would use `switch` for in R.

Comment: So why do you ask here for help with your assignments? Isn't that cheating?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch` in `sapply`:

```
covertdays <- function(x) {c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
  "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")[(x-1) %% 7 + 1]}
covertdays(1:100)
#  [1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday" 
#  [7] "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
# [13] "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday" 
# [19] "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday"
# [25] "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"  
# [31] "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"   
# [37] "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"   
# [43] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday" 
# [49] "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
# [55] "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday" 
# [61] "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday"
# [67] "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"  
# [73] "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"   
# [79] "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"   
# [85] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday" 
# [91] "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
# [97] "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"
```

Comment: You are using `df$day` instead of `x`, also `i %% 7` gives e.g. for `i==7` `0`.

Comment: Maybe: `covertdays <- function(i) {switch((i-1) %% 7 + 1, "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")}` ?